# parse text vertical to horizontal

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I'm looking to parse the following data:

---

```
T  
E  
S  
T  
_  
7  
TTTTTTT  
EEEEEEE  
SSSSSSS  
TTTTTTT  
_______
5679111  
    012
```

---

into something like:

---

```
TEST_7
TEST_5, TEST_6, TEST_7, TEST_9, TEST_10, TEST_11, TEST_12
```

---

Any suggestions could help. Ty

Comment: Are all the fields fixed length? What delimits between `TEST_7` and `TEST_5`?

Comment: I tried sed for text processing and looking into awk and perl for this but no luck so far.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What @KevinMGranger subtly hinted at is that you are lucky for getting answers after mostly ignoring the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please be more careful with your next question and maybe take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

This is basically a transpose operation

```
  awk  'BEGIN {FS=""} 
              {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[NR,i]=$i; 
               if(max<NF)max=NF} 
        END   {for(i=1;i<=max;i++) 
                 {for(j=1;j<=NR;j++) printf "%s",a[j,i]; 
                  print ""}}' file

TEST_7TEST_5 
      TEST_6 
      TEST_7 
TEST_9 
TEST_10
TEST_11
TEST_12
```

you need to explain the rules on how to transform this to your desired layout.

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
txt='''\
T  
E  
S  
T  
_  
7  
TTTTTTT  
EEEEEEE  
SSSSSSS  
TTTTTTT  
_______
5679111  
    012  '''

row_len=max(len(line.rstrip()) for line in txt.splitlines())    
arr=[list('{:{w}}'.format(line.rstrip(), w=row_len)) for line in txt.splitlines()]  
print '\n'.join([''.join(t) for t in zip(*arr)])
```

Or, `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[ ]*\n"} 
          {lines[NR]=$0
           max=length($0)>max ? length($0) : max } 
       END{ for (i=1; i in lines; i++)
                lines[i]=sprintf("%-*s", max, lines[i])
            for (i=1;i<=max; i++){
                for (j=1; j in lines; j++)
                    printf "%s", substr(lines[j], i, 1)
                print ""
            }
}' file
```

Prints:

```
TEST_7TEST_5 
      TEST_6 
      TEST_7 
      TEST_9 
      TEST_10
      TEST_11
      TEST_12
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk (well GNU awk for `-F ''`):

```
$ awk -F '' '
NR!=1 && NF!=p {
    for(i=1;i<=p;i++)
        printf "%s%s",a[i],(i==p?ORS:"")
    delete a
    p=NF }
NR==1 || NF==p {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        a[i]=a[i] $i
    p=NF
    j++ }
END { 
    for(i=1;i<=p;i++)
        printf "%s%s",a[i],(i==p?ORS:", ") }
' file
TEST_7
TEST_5 , TEST_6 , TEST_7 , TEST_9 , TEST_10, TEST_11, TEST_12
```

It detects change (and prints buffered) when record length (`NF` actually) changes.